# Разместить данные на станице получаемые через AJAX. JSON PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

Не получается разместить данные на странице.

AJAX скрипт

```
    function getOrgsToday(){
        $.post( 
            "/kredo/getData.php", 
            { 
                paramFam: "123" 
            }, 
            onAjaxSuccess
        );
            function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
                document.getElementById('org1').innerHTML = data.t800; 
                document.getElementById('org2').innerHTML = data.t900;
                document.getElementById('org3').innerHTML = data.t1000;
                document.getElementById('org4').innerHTML = data.t1100;
                document.getElementById('org5').innerHTML = data.t1200;
                document.getElementById('org6').innerHTML = data.t1300;
                document.getElementById('org7').innerHTML = data.t1400;
                document.getElementById('org8').innerHTML = data.t1500;
                document.getElementById('org9').innerHTML = data.t1600;
            };
    };
```

getData.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
//header('Content-Type: application/json');
require 'dbData.php'; 
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
    printf("Ошибка при загрузке набора символов utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Текущий набор символов: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($conn));
}
//echo json_encode(array("name"=>"John","time"=>"2pm"));
$famil = $_POST['paramFam'];
$sql_main = "SELECT * FROM main WHERE date_ex='" . date('Y-m-d') . "' AND famil=". $famil .";";
    $result_main = $conn->query($sql_main);
    while ($row = $result_main->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo json_encode(array('t800'=>$row['8_00'],
        't900'=>$row['9_00'],
        't1000'=>$row['10_00'],
        't1100'=>$row['11_00'],
        't1200'=>$row['12_00'],
        't1300'=>$row['13_00'],
        't1400'=>$row['14_00'],
        't1500'=>$row['15_00'],
        't1600'=>$row['16_00']));
    };
mysqli_close($conn);?>
```

<del>Он просто ничего не делает, и в консоли ничего нет.</del>
Теперь он работает, но вписывает вместо нужных данных undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Понял в чём была проблема. Просто надо было добавить 
`var jData = JSON.parse(data);`
и заменить data на jData.